# Why didn't the abducted victims talk?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

In the movie Prisoners (2013), the abducted victims ([Alex Jones](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0200452/?ref_=tt_cl_t7), [Bob Taylor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2810287/?ref_=tt_cl_t14) and then Anna and Joy) didn't talk -that much-

Anna and Joy maybe didn't talk because they were shocked and tired but what about Alex and Bob?

Also, Alex didn't even talk when he was under torture by Keller. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the trauma.

We didn't see much of Anna and Joy after being taken. There was just a short scene as Joy remembers it, and their mouth were duct-taped ("It put tape on our mouths"). In the hospital, we learn that Joy was drugged and thus almost completely unable to speak.

Alex and Bob were both very traumatized by their kidnapping.

Early in the movie, we learn that Alex has the intelligence of a ten year old boy. Later on, we learn that he suffered another trauma, besides the kidnapping: some kind of an accident that involved snakes (that Holly's husband kept) which was intensified by the fact that, in Holly's words, "Alex had a fear of them". Since then "Alex never talks very much", "Well, he talks, you know. *Good morning*, *good night*,... that sort of thing. Hard to get too much more than that out of him". You can read more about Alex in [this Christian's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/15187/5589) to a somewhat related question.

As for Bob, he is also clearly suffering from a trauma induced by the kidnapping. He is recreating the scene (thus for a while implicating himself as a kidnapper), he knows what the girls are going through,... he simply cracked a long time ago, probably even before or right after he got away.

Comment: Loki also says that Bob Taylor was drugged with an lsd-ketamine-cocktail and therefore couldn't remember anything.